# How to detect touch when you are moving over a button

Tags: android

I have created a button at the center of the layout with width 50dp.If I touch the screen at left extreme side of the layout(where the is no button) and hold down (Keep pressing ) till I reach the button in center then it should detect the touch .How can I do that .I have tried both onCLicklistener() and onTouchListener() but I still cannot detect the touch .
Basically like gesture but I thought button had a way of detecting that.

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

// Toast text : entered within button


         return false;
        }
       }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set Click or Touch listener to Button which is 50dp width at center, then the listener will get callback only if the user click/touch initiating from button.

While in your problem case, You are initiating click/touch from outside and coming to button.

So, button listener will not get callback from Android Framework

For your requirement to work, we need to add some logic, i have tried to add it here :

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parentLayout" ... >

    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonCenter ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
// apply touch listener to parentLayout
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCenter);
parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

parent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Log.d("tag","in onTouch...");
        checkTouch(event);

         return true;
        }
       });

// check if touch entered button area

// save button left, right, top and bottom edge

// update : This is API i found on google documentation
float[] params;
button.getLocationOnScreen(params);

public void checkTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    if(x >= param[0] && x <= (param[0]+button.getWidth())) {
        if(y >= param[1] && y <= (param[1]+button.getHeight())) {
            Log.d("tag","this touch is in button area");
            // do what you want to do when touch/click comes in button area
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: buttonLeft <= x <= buttonRight is giving an error should it be buttonLeft <= x&&x <= buttonRight ?

Comment: I tried   if(buttonLeft <= x&&x <= buttonRight) {
        if(buttonTop <= y&&y <= buttonBottom) {  but for some reason its not working on the button but above the button.Please can you look into the logic .I guess its more favorable to the top outside the button and not inside the button.

Comment: `if((buttonLeft <= x) && (x <= buttonRight)) { if((buttonTop <= y) && (y <= buttonBottom))` use this one

Comment: This logic is not working for some reason if((buttonLeft <= x) && (x <= buttonRight)) { if((buttonTop <= y) && (y <= buttonBottom)) .Please let me know where I might be going wrong.Thanks Kushal for your time.I really appreciate it.Almost working.

Comment: It might be cause x=event.getx() and y =event.gety() is not matching.But why?

Comment: Sorry Kushal.I checked button.gettop() its showing 50dp but its more than that .I guess I need to gettop()  is not working properly.

Comment: getTop() returns Top position of your button. I did not understand what you are saying?

Comment: Sorry Kushal for the confusion.Currently I have Main_parent layout within which the are 2 relative layouts of 100dp each.And the button is in the second layout .But when I say Button.gettop() it gives 70dp but its actually around 170dp.So,gettop() takes within parent layout and not the entire parent screen.How can I get within entire parent/main parent and not just the layout the button is in?

Comment: I have used  void getLocationOnScreen() API.. It is fine API providing location of our View on screen.. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int[]%29]

Comment: Thanks Kushal.Adding parent_layout.gettop() to both x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you place a touch MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN event is dispatched on the view which you touch and as you move MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE events will be dispatched for every pixel point moved and until you release viz. until MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event is dispatched on that same view the events will not be handed over to any other view. 
That is why it is not detecting on the button since it is actually the event of its parent view. So write an ontouchlistener on the parent and in that handle the touch according to the event.getRawX() & event.getRawY() positions in pixels.